# simple RESTFul Webservices using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new to Spring boot . I wrote a simple code that don"y have any problem in GET but when I want to POST and add a student  it showing Whitelabel Error Page. here is my code

```html
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test1Application {
 public static HashMap<Long, Student> hmstudent;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  hmstudent=new HashMap<Long,Student>();
  Student one=new Student("Ali","Math");
  hmstudent.put(one.getId(),one);
  SpringApplication.run(Test1Application.class, args);
  Student two=new Student("Mohamad","Persian");
  hmstudent.put(two.getId(),two);
 }
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value="/rest/student")
 class StudentService{

  @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public HashMap<Long,Student> getAllStudents(){
   return Test1Application.hmstudent;
  }

 }
 @RequestMapping(value="/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public Student addStudent(@RequestParam(value="name") String name
   ,@RequestParam(value="subject",defaultValue = "unknown") String subject){

  Student student1=new Student(name,subject);
  Test1Application.hmstudent.put(student1.getId(),student1);
  return student1;
 }
}
```

Comment: What address are you trying to visit to POST to? And using what tool?

Comment: As I can see, your post method is not in controller class.